# Pandas manipulate data points

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

[image]

Hello everyone, I would like to redesign the date column. It should be date format instead of 201501 but I couldn't handle it. Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html)

Comment: It does not work. Error occured ' ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,month,year] is missing'

Comment: You need to specify the format. In your case, it's `%Y%m`

Comment: Yay!! it works thank you very much. I thought of the more complex solutions!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
pd.to_datetime("201601", format="%Y%m")
```

In your case this might be something like:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
```